# Cakephp Ajax Login is loggin in even with wrong data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a simple html form to login outside my cake structure, I send the login data via jquery to my login function:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

            $this->request->data['Appuser']['password'] = Security::hash($this->request->data['password']);
            $this->request->data['Appuser']['name'] = $this->request->data['name'];

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl(array('action' => 'returnUserData')));
            }else{
                $this->response->body(json_encode('Login failed!'));
            }
        }elseif($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

The very strange thing is:

- the login via post from /view/users/login.ctp form works perfectly!
- When I try to login from "outside" via ajax, I am always logged in even with wrong access details and get the data from function 'returnUserData'

  $('#login').click(function() {

  ```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/api/login',
                data: {
                    name:     $("#username").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

        });
  ```

When I set a debug(); after  if ($this->request->is('ajax')) I can see it, so the script seems to go into the right if section. But I don't get it, why the $this->Auth->login always return true...?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: check $this->data in case of ajax request

Comment: I am using 2.3.
When I am using $this->data only I get this message: Indirect modification of overloaded property ApiController::$data has no effect